# Long reloading time in Rails development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have application, quite big on Rails 5.0.7.2 and Ruby 2.6. But for sometime local development is real pain. When I change one file and try to reload endpoint which serves only JSON response it took almost a minute to get response. I noticed that all controllers under `app/controllers` and subdirectories are getting loaded once again, like in the first request after booting the app. Serving responses without code changes is fast, only after changing something in code it took long time on first reload.

My `config/environments/development.rb` file looks like:

```rb
Webapp::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Allow to see previews on development.
  config.action_mailer.show_previews = true
  config.action_mailer.preview_path = Rails.root.join('spec', 'mailers', 'previews')

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # Use an evented file watcher to asynchronously detect changes in source code,
  # caching actions and page fragments
  # routes, locales, etc. This feature depends on the listen gem.
  # config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
end
```

I have already tried `EventedFileUpdateChecker`, but it didn't change anything.

Most of the controllers I have under `app/controllers/api` directory in `Api` module.

I am developing on OSX.

Comment: Not into RoR anymore but do you use some kind of special hot module reload? Are you developing on a windows machine?

Comment: We need to know what platform/environment you are seeing this behavior in (os/version, Windows Subsystem for Linux, Docker, etc.)

Comment: Do you still have Spring in your project (https://github.com/rails/spring)?

Comment: It is OSX, both in and outside Docker. Spring is included in Gemfile but starting server with or without spring doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

It was not caused by the framework configuration itself. All my issues disappeared when I removed gems like `better_errors`, `meta_request` and `caller_binding` from my `Gemfile`.